# JS Global/Function Scope Understanding

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope, hoisting

I'm currently enrolled in a Javascript class and I wanted some help understanding how exactly scope works. We've been over topics like global scope, function scope, hoisting in class but I'm struggling to put it all together. So the question that I was specifically looking at consisted of figuring out what the following code outputted:

```
x = 1;
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
var c = function (a, b, c) {
    document.write(x);
    document.write(a);
    var f = function (a, b, c) {
        b = a;
        document.write(b);
        b = c;
        var x = 5;
    }
    f(a, b, c);
    document.write(b);
    var x = 10;
}
c(8, 9, 10);
document.write(b); 
document.write(x);
```

Now the solution that we have is that code will print out  undefined 8 8 9 10 1

I needed some help understanding how exactly this happens. Specifically, I don't understand how the values of b vary depending on the statement we're looking at. Would appreciate it if someone could just run through the whole step-by-step for me. 
Thanks!

Comment: What did you think would happen? What exactly is unexpected?

Answer (score 1):

I commented the code a little so hopefully it makes more sense. The most important concepts to understand is variable hoisting and function scope. There is only function scope in JavaScript.

```
x = 1;
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
var c = function (a, b, c) {

    /* this `x` refers to the new `x` variable initialized below
     * near the closing function `c` brace.
     * It is undefined because of hoisting, and gets assigned
     * a value where it was initialized below.
     */
    console.log(x); // undefined

    /* this `a` refers to this `a` parameter,
     * because it is within this function `c` scope.
     */
    console.log(a);

    var f = function (a, b, c) {

        /* this `b` refers to this `b` parameter,
         * because it is within this function `f` scope.
         *
         * this `a` refers to this `a` parameter,
         * because it is within this function `f` scope.
         */
        b = a;
        console.log(b);

         /* this `b` still refers to `b` in this function `f` scope.
          *
          * this `c` refers to this `c` parameter,
          * because it is within this function scope.
          */
        b = c;

        /* this is a new `x` variable because it is
         * with this function `f` scope and there is no parameter `x`.
         */
        var x = 5;
    };

    /* these `a`, `b`, and `c` variables refer to
     * this function `c` parameters.
     */
    f(a, b, c); // f(5, 10, 10)
    console.log(b); // 9

   /* this is a new `x` variable because it is
    * with this function `c` scope and there is no parameter `x`.
    */
    var x = 10;
};

c(8, 9, 10);

/* `a`, `b`, `c`, and `x` have not been touched,
 * because the other `a`,`b`,`c` variables were parameter names,
 * and other `x` variables were initialized within a different scope.
 */
console.log(b); // 10 
console.log(x); // 1
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/pubaponeje/1/edit)**

Comment: I noticed you said the console.log(b) after the f(a,b,c) statement executes to a '10'. Can you tell me how exactly we get the middle 8 and 9 in our output, as in which lines produce those and why

Comment: @DavidW that is clearly a mistake. It should be 9. Thanks for pointing out the error.